# Rails asset pipeline: fonts not found

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, sass

I have a strange error, where some fonts are found but some aren't. Basically I have two fonts `font1` (custom font from IconMoon) and `Brandon` (from fonts.com). My directory structure is

```
- app
  - assets
    - fonts
      - font1.eot
      - ...
      - 172fdde2-f56b-433a-a6e2-ebeab9dfb588.eot
      - ...
```

I'm using SCSS to load my fonts:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font1';
  src:font-url('font1.eot?-kpzpl9');
  src:font-url('font1.eot?#iefix-kpzpl9') format('embedded-opentype'),
  font-url('font1.woff?-kpzpl9') format('woff'),
  font-url('font1.ttf?-kpzpl9') format('truetype'),
  font-url('font1.svg?-kpzpl9#font1') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face{
  font-family:'Brandon Grot W01 Medium';
  src:font-url('172fdde2-f56b-433a-a6e2-ebeab9dfb588.eot?#iefix');
  src:font-url('172fdde2-f56b-433a-a6e2-ebeab9dfb588.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
  font-path('50ca6f6f-b64d-4af0-9b30-526cf363d87e.woff2') format('woff2'),
  font-url('050c2cbf-b818-4b8e-b6d2-71b70478bd9d.woff') format('woff'),
  font-url('7da41ce3-b3fd-4fca-a85f-4f3099884c15.ttf') format('truetype'),
  font-url('37c88f3d-9532-4547-9e11-7cca7f66048c.svg#37c88f3d-9532-4547-9e11-7cca7f66048c') format('svg');
}
```

When I try to load the `font1` fonts, everything works. But when I try to load the `Brandon` font I get 404 errors. This is the generated CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'font1';
  src: url(/assets/font1.eot?-kpzpl9);
  src: url(/assets/font1.eot?#iefix-kpzpl9) format("embedded-opentype"), url(/assets/font1.woff?-kpzpl9) format("woff"), url(/assets/font1.ttf?-kpzpl9) format("truetype"), url(/assets/font1.svg?-kpzpl9#font1) format("svg");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Brandon Grot W01 Medium';
  src: url(/assets/172fdde2-f56b-433a-a6e2-ebeab9dfb588.eot?#iefix);
  src: url(/assets/172fdde2-f56b-433a-a6e2-ebeab9dfb588.eot?#iefix) format("eot"), "/assets/50ca6f6f-b64d-4af0-9b30-526cf363d87e.woff2" format("woff2"), url(/assets/050c2cbf-b818-4b8e-b6d2-71b70478bd9d.woff) format("woff"), url(/assets/7da41ce3-b3fd-4fca-a85f-4f3099884c15.ttf) format("truetype"), url(/assets/37c88f3d-9532-4547-9e11-7cca7f66048c.svg#37c88f3d-9532-4547-9e11-7cca7f66048c) format("svg");
}
```

Calls to `/assets/font1.eot` result in a `200` and calls to `/assets/172fdde2-f56b-433a-a6e2-ebeab9dfb588.eot` result in a `404`.

I'm not sure why this happens, because they are in the same directory. The logs look like this

```
Started GET "/assets/font1.eot" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-05 10:38:22 +0100
Served asset /font1.eot - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Started GET "/assets/172fdde2-f56b-433a-a6e2-ebeab9dfb588.eot" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-05 10:39:25 +0100
Served asset /172fdde2-f56b-433a-a6e2-ebeab9dfb588.eot - 404 Not Found (6ms)
```

I'm on Rails 3.2.9

Any ideas on how to debug this issue?

Comment: Have you precompiled locally?

Comment: You sure you've font family with `172fdde2-f56b-433a-a6e2-ebeab9dfb588` name?

Comment: No I haven't precompiled locally

Comment: @Mr.Alien this was copy & paste from fonts.com. Must the filenames match the font family name?

Comment: @23tux no such requirement... it should work if the file exists and the file name is correct.

Comment: Are you precompiling first?

Comment: No, I'm not precompiling first, `public/assets` doesn't exist, it happens in development env

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is caused by the hyphens in the name.

If you rename your files to use underscores instead, for example `172fdde2_f56b_433a_a6e2_ebeab9dfb588.eot`, and then replace the hyphens with underscores in your css files, everything should work.

It's caused by sprockets trying to strip out fingerprints when resolving the asset. Ultimately it strips out part or all of the filename and then finds no matching file.

Comment: thanks, that worked! This is something you have to know, otherwise you search forever ;)